# how to know whether checkbox is checked or not django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this in a form in my html file:

```
<input type="checkbox" id ="hide_name" value="hidden">
```

what should i put in my models to know whether this checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's the chain of events for someone checking the checkbox and that information reaching your server.

First, they press a "submit" button on the page, and they're sent to a destination URL that you've specified in your form HTML.  Their browser requests that page from your server with HTTP POST (usually), which includes all of the data from that form as part of the request.

Django checks that URL against your list of valid urls and sends it to the appropriate view.  The view in question can then check the request object passed into the view to get the POST data (it's stored as a dictionary in [request.POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)).

You can then do whatever you want with it in your view, including passing it to your model.

If you are working with forms you might be better off letting Django render your forms, instead of coding them in HTML yourself.  See the [forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) for more on this.

Comment: from what i understood in the model i will use something like this    request.POST['hide_name'] but how will i know if it is checked or not, im not using django forms because i only need this check mark

Comment: The code to handle the checkbox contents needs to be in your view, not your model.  If `request` is the name of the request object being passed through to the view, then `request.POST['hide_name']` will be a boolean -- if it is `True`, then the box is checked.  If it is `False` then the box is unchecked.

Comment: Actually, cancel that -- now that I think about it, it's possible that it won't be `False` but instead simply be absent from the dictionary if it is unchecked.  In that case you need to test for its existence with `if 'hide_name' in request.POST`.  Try both and see which works.